# How to increase max_execution_time in PHP

Tags: php

I want to increase `max_execution` time for my site. I have tried some methods to do this with out any success and need help.

What I already tried:

- I set my site in sub-folder I have create php.ini for that folder and along with set `max_execution_time=259200`
- In my code file I set `set_ini('max_execution_time','259200')`
- I set root php.ini `max_execution_time`

How can I set `max_execution_time` from cpanel for my server?

What I already done:

1. change php.ini increase max_execution_time = 2592000
2. add `set_ini('max_execution_time','2592000');` in my script file in starting of file
3. add `set_time_limit(2592000);` in my script file in starting of file
4. concern with host provider due to shared server support doesn't work

Comment: This is only changeable for you if you have the proper rights on the server. Talk to your hosting people (I assume you're not running your own based on the question)

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);` :)

Comment: I have do this but with out resolution I set this code in php script

Comment: I have do this but with out resolution I set this code in php script I call it contents.php In this file I set this set_time_limit(0) and also (3600) at starting of file

Comment: See my answer mate. I have a feeling it is restricted on your server.

Comment: I agree with you my host provider does not allow me do this from cpanel I need other method for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the limit with `set_time_limit()`
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

But you can only change this if the admin of your hosting server has allowed you to do so.

You can shoot them an email and ask for what you want or if they don't allow it, change your code into executable chunks that each run only a couple sec(or less) and a loop that calls all of them.

Depending on your application this could be done any number of ways and might be a different question altogether.

Comment: for($i=1;$i<$match_total[1];$i+=50){
echo "http://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/view?page=".$counter++."<br>";
$all_page = file_get_contents("http://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/view?page=".$counter++."");
preg_match_all('/http:\/\/www.cardkingdom.com\/catalog\/item\/([0-9]+)/',$all_page,$match2);
$counts =0;
foreach($match2[0] as $match){
$input  = file_get_contents($match);
preg_match('/http:\/\/www.cardkingdom.com\/\/product_images\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/([0-9_]+)standard.jpg/', $input , $proimg);

}
}

Comment: can please clear me how can i change my code into executable chunks

Comment: You should add this into another question and submit the url here. Rewriting some PHP from a comment is not gona help anyone in SO.

Comment: @user3781881 Please mark this as the answer if it answered your question and link new question below your question that you may have posted. Thanks